# Overlay area stays on top after searching a list UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UIView with a list of items. When I click the search bar the keyboard comes up and the rest of the screen contains a grey overlay.

[image]

When I click on the grey overlay the keyboard disappears, however the overlay area stays on top and is not disappearing. What is the root of cause of this problem? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it:-

**Write this in console:-** by giving breakpoint in the view controller

```
 po [self.view subviews]

(id) $1 = 0x0a3155f0 <__NSArrayM 0xa3155f0>(
<ATShadowTableView: 0xc341600; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 44; 320 411); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xa627200>; layer = <CALayer: 0xa626d30>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>,
<UISearchBar: 0xa618f40; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = ''; layer = <CALayer: 0xa619040>>,
<UIControl: 0xa329fc0; frame = (0 44; 320 455); alpha = 0.8; opaque = NO; animations = { opacity=<CABasicAnimation: 0xa32b4e0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0xa32a060>>
)
```

**Last object (UIControl) in self.subview is what we want to remove. So**

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
...
    [self performSelector:@selector(removeOverlay) withObject:nil afterDelay:.01f];
}

- (void)removeOverlay
{
    [[self.view.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
[searchCon setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

where searchCon is your UISearchDisplayController.

Hope it helps